# Getting Started with BI

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I recently started a new job in BI. I have done very well at adapting my T-SQL skills to working on a BI data warehouse. My problem is that the field is so diverse and the tools available are almost limitless, I dont know what to focus my research on. Can someone point me in the right direction? Im not looking for a "how to" but more best practice type of information. If you have worked in BI for several years where would you tell an entry level employee to start? What did you whish you knew when you started that you know now?

I constently feel like i have too many options and feel that if i dont pick the correct path that my work is useless...I bet someone else has experienced this when starting to work in BI.

Comment: I suggest starting with the tasks with which you have been assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Dan, starting with the tasks assigned. Do not search the internet for answers. Spend time reading books. By finding the solution in books, you learn a lot along the way. By *googling* your queries (which I'm sure must have been answered), you do not learn anything new.

Apart from that, you can start learning the basics of dimensional modelling, star schemas, snowflakes, slowly changing dimensions etc. Get used to these buzzwords. A good book to start can be Ralph Kimball's Datawarehouse Toolkit ([http://www.amazon.com/The-Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Dimensional/dp/0471200247](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247))

Vijay